# paper-item's Displaying Side by Side (Inside paper-menu, Inside paper-menu-button)

Tags: polymer-1.0

I have a paper-menu-button in my code that looks as follows:

```
<paper-menu-button style="position:absolute; right:0; bottom:0" vertical-align="bottom" horizontal-align="right">
    <paper-button icon="expand-more" class="dropdown-trigger" style="background-color:#00A9FE; top:2px" raised>
        <span>Send</span>
        <iron-icon icon="expand-more"></iron-icon>
    </paper-button>

    <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
        <paper-item on-click="_setPriority">Urgent</paper-item>
        <paper-item on-click="_setHigh">High</paper-item>
        <paper-item on-click="_setMedium">Medium</paper-item>
        <paper-item on-click="_setLow">Low</paper-item>
    </paper-menu>
</paper-menu-button>
```

When a user is logged into the system, the list displays correctly, like so:
[image]

However, when there isn't a user logged into the system, the list displays as follows:
[image]

This function is on a help button that needs to be available whether a user is logged into the system or not.

There are no warnings and no errors in the console when this item is loaded. The code is no different when a user is logged in or not. The styles for this element is no different from when a user is logged in or not.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? Does anyone know why this would happen?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the imports to `paper-menu` and `paper-item`.

They must be included in the page that loads when a user logs in, which is why it worked with a user logged in but not when there is no user logged in.

I also made the assumption that importing `paper-menu-button` would import `paper-menu` and `paper-item`.